# C# to JSON conversion, dictionary

Tags: c#, json

I have a class as follows and I want its JSON signature. It's the last property `Actions` that I am unsure about how to transfer to JSON. I have tried C# to JSON converter online but it gives null for `Actions`.

```
 public class Notification
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string Users { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public List<Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>> Action { get; set; }
    }
```

Any help here would be most appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using [JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.serialize(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Newtonsoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json for that class would be:

```
{  
   "Name":"Test",
   "Body":"TestBody",
   "Subject":"TestSubject",
   "Users":"TestUsers",
   "Date":"9/22/2016 12:26:20 PM",
   "Action":[  
      {  
         "key":{  
            "innerKey":"value"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

for this C# code:

```
var notification = new Notification()
{
    Name = "Test",
    Body = "TestBody",
    Subject = "TestSubject",
    Users = "TestUsers",
    Date = DateTime.Now.ToString(),
    Action = new List<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>()
    {
        new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>()
        {
            { "key", new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "innerKey", "value" } } }
        }
    }
};
```